# Array formula to merge several columns into one from another sheet. Is it possible?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm using the following to pull data from a response sheet into another sheet:

```
=transpose(query(transpose('Form Responses 1'!BR175:BS175),,COLUMNS('Form Responses 1'!BR175:BS175)))
```

This allows me to merge several columns into one. However, when new responses come in, the transpose function doesn't fill automatically because its not calculated.

source: https://www.benlcollins.com/formula-examples/array-formulas-forms/

Is it possible to implement an array from another sheet? Or is there any better way of doing this?

I need my new sheet to pull a column range from Form Responses 1, and merge all columns into a single column without creating new columns. :|

Comment: Can you share a sanitised copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]Please try the following instead

```
=ArrayFormula(Sheet1!B17:B22&" "&Sheet1!C17:C22&" "&Sheet1!D17:D22)
```

*(Adjust ranges to your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)

Comment: While the formula works, It actually doesn't work. I mean, the array pulls from my response sheet. But not when a new entry comes in. So frustrating. Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Change the ranges to open ranges Meaning: change `Sheet1!B17:B22` to `Sheet1!B17:B` etc.

Comment: It works well but when I receive a new response from Google Forms, the values don't transfer to the sheet. It's like the entire row is just deleted. :/

Comment: That is odd. Let me try it myself.

Comment: Right?! It's hard to even describe what's happening here. I have coworkers fill out my form, submit it, and its on sheet1. Great. However, it never makes it to sheet 2 where I merge many columns with your formula

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214746/discussion-between-marikamitsos-and-t0m3k).

Comment: This is the array i used: =ARRAYFORMULA(query(transpose('Form Responses 1'!T176:U176),,COLUMNS('Form Responses 1'!T176:U176))) 
 
Also tried to use transpose and same thing is happening. I dont think it matters what I use. Maybe this is a google sheet thing?

Comment: Please come to the chat

Comment: **Just tried it and works just fine**. Please try it (submit responses) at this [Test form](https://forms.gle/vWSvzvQo4Mmxne8g7) and see the results at the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P5JLScnG3zEWXyjNU7lSQY1Hr_QN1yF7RFTFhYmg1kQ/edit?rm=minimal#gid=2120522439)

Comment: marikamitsos, 

Your formula works! Thank you so much.  I don't suppose you by chance know how to get rid of spaces? Some of my cells have spaces before/after text depending on what column is merged when other columns are not merged due to them being empty.

Comment: nevermind, i got it:

=ArrayFormula(trim('Form Responses 1'!Z2:Z&" "&'Form Responses 1'!AA2:AA&""))